# JPA, How to find an object that has composite id?

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, find, datastore

Based on second approach [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13033039/513413) I designed my JPA class.

```
@Entity(name = "SearchKeywordJPA")
@IdClass(SearchKeywordJPA.SearchKeyId.class)
public class SearchKeywordJPA implements Comparable<SearchKeywordJPA> {

    @Id
    private String keyword;
    @Id
    private long date;
    private String userUUID;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        SearchKeywordJPA that = (SearchKeywordJPA) o;

        if (date != that.date) return false;
        if (!keyword.equals(that.keyword)) return false;
        if (!userUUID.equals(that.userUUID)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = keyword.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (int) (date ^ (date >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + userUUID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchKeywordJPA{" +
                "keyword='" + keyword + '\'' +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", userUUID='" + userUUID + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUserUUID() {
        return userUUID;
    }

    public void setUserUUID(String userUUID) {
        this.userUUID = userUUID;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SearchKeywordJPA searchRecord) {
        long comparedDate = searchRecord.date;

        if (this.date > comparedDate) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.date == comparedDate) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**********************
     * Key class
     **********************/
    public class SearchKeyId {
        private int id;
        private int version;
    }
}
```

In my servlet I want to check datastore and store my object if is not exist.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
            for(SearchKeywordJPA item: applicationList) {
                if(!isRecorded(item))
                    storeRecord(item);
            }

        }

    private boolean isRecorded(SearchKeywordJPA record) {
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

        SearchKeywordJPA item = em.find(SearchKeywordJPA.class, record);
        return item != null;

    }

    private void storeRecord(SearchKeywordJPA record) {
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

        em.persist(record);
    }
```

However when I run, application crashes and log says

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: Received a request to find an object of type com.twitterjaya.model.SearchKeywordJPA identified by SearchKeywordJPA{keyword='airasia', date=1335680686149, userUUID='FFFF0000'}.  This is not a valid representation of a primary key for an instance of com.twitterjaya.model.SearchKeywordJPA.
```

What is the reason? any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You pass an instance of the **IdClass** into *em.find* ... i.e SearchKeyId. Obviously if you really have an IdClass that has [no equals/hashCode/toString/constructor](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/application_identity.html#Multiple_PrimaryKey_field) then you will likely get many problems. Those problems will only be increased by using an ancient plugin for GAE/Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

If your Key is

```
@Entity(name = "SearchKeywordJPA")
@IdClass(SearchKeywordJPA.SearchKeyId.class)
public class SearchKeywordJPA implements Comparable<SearchKeywordJPA> {
```

you are doing it wrong.

1. IdClass does not need any annotation of @IdClass just the  @Id
   annotation.
2. Key can not be an entity.
3. Need to implements Serializable , comparable is not needed
4. Need to override equals and hascode and have no arg constructor

Class key need to be as follows.

```
public class SearchKeyId implements Serializable {

    private String keyword;

    private long date;
```

And your entity I assume something like this.

```
@Entity(name = "SearchKeywordJPA")
@IdClass(SearchKeyId.class)
public class SearchKeywordJPA {
    @Id
    private String keyword;
    @Id
    private long date;

    private String userUUID;
```

- Just consider that find method will use the SearchKey.class to find
  the entities.
- Fields that are in the IdClass need to have @Id annotation in the entity.
- Key can not be an entity on its own.
- Comparable is not really needed as all the comparison are placed in the IdClass

Comment: Fields of an IdClass do *not* need to be annotated. It's an "id" so all fields of the IdClass are part of the id.

Comment: Yes my bad, I just copy the code and forgot that thanks.