# Bug in Hibernate or my misunderstanding of composite Id?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm not big guru of JPA, but this behaviour looks strange to me, please comment!

I'm trying to persist nested Objects:
each Employee contains Set of Departments

if Department `@Id` is declared as `@Generated` int everything works fine. But it is inconvenient and I try to declare as `@Id` two fields (employee id + department id). But I get

```
EJBTransactionRolledbackException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

on **both** merge and persist. Is it OK?

Some details:

Departments are declared this way

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "snils")
private Set<DepartmentRecord> departments = new HashSet<>();
```

the relation is unidirectional and Persons are not declared in Departments

I populate departments this way:

```
record.getDepartments().add(new DepartmentRecord(snils, department));
```

Person is created this way:

```
Person record = em.find(Person.class, snils);

if (record == null)
        record = new Person();

record.setSnils(snils);
record.setFullname(fullname);
record.resetLastActive();
```

on em.persist(record) or em.merge(record) I get an Exception.
Wrapping it to try catch block doesn't help

```
Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
```

What I need - is just update Person and Departments. Is it possible without boilerplate code (removing cascade, doing separate departments search et c )???

My environment: CentOS7, java8, Wildfly 10.2

Persons table is :

```
snils      | character varying(255) | not null
blocked    | integer                | not null
fullname   | character varying(255) | 
lastactive | date                   | 
    Indexes:
"hr_workers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (snils)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "hr_departments" CONSTRAINT "fk49rcpg7j54eq6fpf9x2nphnpu"     FOREIGN KEY (snils) REFERENCES hr_workers(snils)
```

Department table is :

```
snils      | character varying(255) | not null
department | character varying(255) | not null
lastactive | date                   | 
     Indexes:
"hr_departments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (snils, department)
     Foreign-key constraints:
"fk49rcpg7j54eq6fpf9x2nphnpu" FOREIGN KEY (snils) REFERENCES hr_workers(snils)
```

Entity Person (actually SNILSRecord):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hr_workers")
public class SNILSRecord implements Serializable {

@Id
private String snils;
private String fullname;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "snils")
private Set<DepartmentRecord> departments = new HashSet<>();

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastActive;
private int blocked;
```

//getters and setters

}

Entity Department:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hr_departments")
public class DepartmentRecord implements Serializable {

@Id
private String snils;
@Id
private String department;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastActive;
```

Comment: Can you also post the DB scheam for Person and department. PLease also post the complete Persong Entity with the composite id

Comment: You need to specify composite key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa

Comment: Done! Please comment