# Many to One Mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

The following mapping is giving an error of

> A Foreign key refering db.KarateInvoice from db.KarateInvoiceDetail
>   has the wrong number of column. should be 1

Invoice Entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private long                      id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "companyid")
@Id
private Company                   company;
@Id
private short                     fiscalYear;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "karateInvoiceDetails")
private List<KarateInvoiceDetail> karateInvoiceDetails;
```

Invoice Detail:

```
@Id
private short         seqNo;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceCompanyId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceFiscalYear") })
private KarateInvoice invoice;
@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "studentId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "studentCompanyId") })
private KarateStudent student;
```

Company Entity:

```
@Id
private long        id;
```

Idea is to have an `Invoice` table with a composite of (id, fiscalyear, and companyId) and `InvoiceDetail` with a composite key of (seqNo, InvoiceId, InvoiceFiscalYear, and InvoiceCompanyId).

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?  I just tested the mapping on 5.2.7 and I don't see this being problematic.

Comment: I'm using hibernate 5.1

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explicitly reference the Invoice columns on the @JoinColumn annotations:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceId"
                  , referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceCompanyId"
               , referencedColumnName="companyId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "karateInvoiceFiscalYear"
               , referencedColumnName="fiscalYear") })
private KarateInvoice invoice;
```

Comment: I think this should work. Will test it and accept the answer if it does.

Comment: ill do some more tests later. IS the error the same?

Comment: One crucial thing.. please add the DDL statements for the tables in question.. this might shed some light on things

Comment: Will do that. It says here that I should use IdClass or embedded id. Will try that too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa