# Spring JPA - entity with two primary key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

There are 3 tables `Label`, `Text` and `Language`:

```
@Entity
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "text_id")
    private Text text;

}
```

Then text:

```
@Entity
public class Text {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "text")
    private List<Label> labels;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    private Language language;

}
```

And finally:

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "language")
    private List<Text> texts;

}
```

What is the best approach to have in the `Text` entity two keys `text_id` and `language_id` that together should be unique and for example Text table would look like this:

```
text_id     language_id     text
------------------------------------
1           1               Example
1           2               Beispiel
```

And then in `LabelRepository` I would be able to define for which language I would like the text?

Answer (score 3):

You can found two solutions here: [How to create and handle composite primary key in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa)

- The first one is based on a @Embeddable class.
- The second one is based on a @IdClass class.

**Summary of the @IdClass solution:**

1- Create a "key" class

```
public class LabelRepositoryKey implements Serializable {
  private Long textId;
  private Long languageId;
}
```

2- Then, use this "key" class in your entity

```
@Entity @IdClass(LabelRepositoryKey.class)
public class LabelRepository {
  @Id
  private Long textId;
  @Id
  private Long languageId;
  @Column(name = "text")
  private String text;
}
```

Comment: Should key class be named `TextKey` instead of `LabelRepositoryKey`?

Comment: I would say no since this is the key of a LabelRepository entry.

Comment: But then I would have to modify the `Text` entity, because for now there is only one primary key and I would not be able to insert to the table two entries with the same id (constraint - `id` and `language_id` should be together unique)