# JPA how ensure uniqueness over 2 fields, string and boolean

Tags: jpa

I want to create an entity containing 2 fields that need to be unique in together. One of the fields is a Boolean:

```
@Entity
public class SoldToCountry {

    private String countryId;


    private Boolean isInt;
}
```

For a given String there should never exist more than 2 entries one with `isInt:true` and the other `isInt:false`.

I read the doc about @Id but it seems that Boolean is not supported. For me it would also be ok to have a unique constraint spanned over both fields and using a generated id.

What is the best way to get this constraint via JPA?

Comment: Have a look at [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html).

Comment: do you want the two fields to be the primary key for the table? or you have another PK, and they are just another constrant on the table?

Comment: in best case 2 fields for PK

Answer (score 1):

If your table has really two fields only, and you want they are unique, then they should be the composite PK of the table. Take a look at [How to create and handle composite primary key in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948)

If, instead, you have another PK, consider Sebastian's comment.

Comment: it would be nice to see an example with a Boolean as part of a PK

Comment: I think there are not problems with booleans in JPA. Provided that your database supports boolean columns. What DB are you using? (I am talking about using @EmbeddedId, not @Id).

Comment: We use Oracle. Thanks i will try. I only read somewhere that only specific bse classes could be part of an id class.

Comment: I am afraid Oracle has no Boolean datatype. Maybe you should change Java datatype to conform to corresponding Oracle column type.