# How to implements entity with 2 entity as primary key with jpa annotation and repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-annotations, jparepository

i want to implement a many to many association with quantity information in it . like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reserves")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Reserve {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupe_id")
    private GroupeSanguin bloodGroup;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Banque banque;
    private int quantity;
}
```

the GroupSanguin and the Banque are two class stored in the database two . here is the code for the two if you need :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupe_sanguins")
public class GroupeSanguin {
    @Id
    private String groupe;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupeSanguin")
    private List<Donneur> donneurs;
}
@Entity @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Banque {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String nom;
    private String adresse;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String telephone;
    private String localisation;
}
```

so my i want to know how to annotate the JpaRepository to take the two as primary key like this and is my annotation good for it to work ?

```
public interface ReserveRepository extends JpaRepository<
Reserve,
//what to put here ?
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found this solutions too.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reserves")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(ReserveId.class) //this annotation will tell that id that the 
// the id will be represented by a class
public class Reserve {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupe_id")
    private GroupeSanguin groupeSanguin;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "banque_id")
    private Banque banque;
    private int quantity;
}
```

and the id class should implements Serializable like this :

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ReserveId implements Serializable {
    private Banque banque;
    private GroupeSanguin groupeSanguin;
}
```

and finally the repository will be like that :

```
@Repository
public interface ReserveRepo extends JpaRepository<Reserve, ReserveId>{}
```

Comment: Yes it's also a solution. But if another entity is linked to Reserve entity you will need 2 columns to do the link.

Comment: i dont what you're saying if there was another entity as an id ?

Comment: No it's the same entity use has FK but it costs 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a JPA question in fact, it's a relationnal database conception.
If Reserve has is **own data** and links with other entity it has it **own Id**
You can add unicity constraint

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reserves", uniqueConstraints={
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"banque_id", "groupe_id"})
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Reserve {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
   

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "groupe_id")
private GroupeSanguin bloodGroup;
   
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "banque_id")
private Banque banque;
private int quantity;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See your Reserve class has nowhere mentioned composite primary key. First you need to fix the model, You can refer to the solution here [How to create and handle composite primary key in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa)