# Entity Id of TimescaleDB + JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, timescaledb

I'm creating Spring Boot application with TimescaleDB. On each timestamp there are object's name(foo, bar, baz, ...), value, etc. I've heard that TimescaleDB uses timestamp as primary key. But @Id on timestamp column returns duplicate values on same timestamp.

Entity.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Entity {
  @Id
  private Timestamp time;

  private Integer value;

  private String name;
}
```

EntityRepository.java

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Timestamp> {
  List<Entity> findByTime(Timestamp time);
}
```

result of findByTime

```
[{"time": 2024-02-26T00:00:00.000, "value": 123, "name": "foo"},
{"time": 2024-02-26T00:00:00.000, "value": 123, "name": "foo"},
{"time": 2024-02-26T00:00:00.000, "value": 123, "name": "foo"},
...
{"time": 2024-02-26T00:00:00.000, "value": 123, "name": "foo"}]
```

Comment: Hey, I guess you can do it using a composite primary key. You need to combine time and name in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa.